# php foreach is listing not drop listing

Tags: php, dropdown

I want to drop list of the year starting from the current year to 8 more years but it is listing them. I cannot select the year from drop-down because all of them are listed. I want them to drop down so I can select which one I want from the list.

```
<?php
class BirthYear
{
    public function year(){
        $years = array(date("Y"));
        foreach($years as $year){
            for($i=0; $i < 8; $i++){
                $y = $year++;
                echo $y."<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}

$y = new BirthYear();
//echo $y->year();
?>
<html>
<style>
    label {
        font-size: 1rem;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    select {
        font-size: .9rem;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
</style>
<select name="birthYear" id="birthYear-select">
    <option value="">Please choose an option</option>
    <option value=""><?php echo $y->year();?></option>
</select>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to output each year wrapped in an `<option></option>`, not all years within one `<option>`…!?

Comment: I think that is what I did here
<option value=""><?php echo $y->year();?></option>

Comment: No, you didn't.

Comment: Does it output `<option>2020</option><option>2021</option>...`? It doesn't.

Comment: Can you explain in code then?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It output <option>20202021...</option>

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! the year() function now returns the year from the current one till the next 8 yeas. you weren't looping through the array, and you weren't even returning anything for the year() which caused it to be null.

```
<?php
class BirthYear
{
    public function year()
    {
        $current_year = date("Y");
        $target_year = $current_year + 8;
        $years = array();
        do {
            array_push($years, $current_year);
            $current_year++;
        } while ($target_year >= $current_year);

        return $years;
    }
}

$y = new BirthYear();
$years = $y->year();
?>

<select name="birthYear" id="birthYear-select">
    <option value="">Please choose an option</option>
    <?php foreach ($years as $year) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $year; ?>"><?php echo $year; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
<?php
class BirthYear
{
    public function year(){
        $y = array();
        $year = date("Y");
        for($i=0; $i < 8; $i++){
            $y[] = $year++;
        }
        return $y;
    }
}

$y = new BirthYear();
?>
<html>
<style>
    label {
        font-size: 1rem;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    select {
        font-size: .9rem;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
</style>
<select name="birthYear" id="birthYear-select">
    <option value="">Please choose an option</option>
    <?php foreach($y->year() as $year) {
        echo "<option value=\"$year\">$year</option>\n";
    }
    ?>

</select>
</html>
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9042c9b444bcc8281f9ef5de313513823477817f

Comment: I took the HTML and put in php and it works. It is not how I wanted it though.
<php ?
class BirthYear
{
    public function year(){
        $years = array(date("Y"));
        foreach($years as $year){
            echo "<select name=\"birthYear\" id=\"birthYear-select\">";
            for($i=0; $i < 8; $i++){
                $y = $year++;
                echo "<option"."Choose year"."</option>";
                echo "<option>".$y."<br>"."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
        }
    }
}
$y = new BirthYear();
echo $y->year();
?>

Comment: That also works but has the downside of adding presentational concerns (<option> tags) into your function. Most of the times it's better to not mix functionality and presentation. But since your code is living in one file and seems to be rather procedural than OOP I guess that's fine with you. ;)